# Subscript out of range while using index match

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub General()
Dim Generic_Selection As Range
Dim Generic As Range
Dim Models As Range
Dim All_Models As Range
Set Generic_Selection = Sheets("Report").Range("Generic_Selection")
Set Generic = Sheets("Data").Range("Generic")
Set Models = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Models")
Set All_Models = Sheets("Data").Range("All_Models")
If Generic_Selection = "" Then
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Generic_Model").ClearContents
Else
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Generic_Model") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Generic, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Models, All_Models, 0), 1)
End If
End Sub
```

Any idea on why this returns as subscript out of range? All the references are correct and it works perfectly without the else statement.

Comment: No idea, but for debugging purposes, break that huge line into two. First assign `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Models, All_Models, 0)` to a variable, `Debug.Print` it to see what it is, and then try to use it in the next line. See which line triggers the error.

Comment: 2 tests: a) comment from the `If` block until the end of the macro, run it and check if there is any error messages / b) If there is no error in test a) then change the `If Then Else` results to two `Msgbox`, one for `If` and other for `Else`. I am suggesting this because I am not being able to perform the comparison `If Generic_Selection = "" Then` and maybe that is the problem.

Comment: well then it must be your index/match. why the extra one at the end of the formula?